# How to prevent href rewrites for Visualforce pages in Lightning Experience?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, hyperlink

On a Visualforce page use in LEX I have a Link like this:

```
<a 
    onclick="{! 'sforce.one.navigateToURL(\"/' item['Id'] + '\")' }"
    href="/one/one.app#/sObject/{!item['Id']}/view"
>
    {!item["Name"]} 
</a>
```

Dual usage of onclick AND href ensures, that it works fine when clicked plus fine if you middle-click, right-click or do something else in the browser with the link. If you go only with navigateToURL() the usability is very very poor.

Now, when I render the page, inspect the generated markup, I get as expected something like

```
<a 
    href="/one/one.app#/sObject/0010Y00000K6lJ5/view"
    onclick="sforce.one.navigateToURL('/0010Y00000K6lJ5')"
>
    A Name
</a>
```

Which is perfectly good and exactly how it needs to be.

The bad things start to happen, when I do a right-click. Then Salesforce seems to want to help by changing the href-attribute like this:

```
href="/one/one.app#/alohaRedirect/one/one.app#/sObject/0010Y00000K6lJ5/view"
```

Which obviously can't work and leads to a broken and faulty link. Again, this happens very late: at the time, when the link is clicked with the right mouse button - not earlier - not just after the page is rendered. There is a listener on the a-tags doing that rewrite in main.js.

By the way:

- an immediate middle-click works as expected - this is only on right-click
- I think it has started with summer'17 and was not happening in spring'17 but I'm not 100% sure

**Questions**

- why does this happen at all? I see no need, if href a written properly, everything is fine without that. I suspect, that Salesforce is trying to do something good for old VF-pages which are not aware of LEX and come with bad hrefs, like only "/0010Y00000K6lJ5" or "/0010Y00000K6lJ5/e"
- how can I prevent this this feature from crippling my hrefs? How can I turn this behavior off OR how can I write my hrefs in order to work (as described) and being immune against this interaction?

Comment: As for prevention, you may need to implement [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: @AdrianLarson : I found already a workaround by adding my own listener on the "contextmenu" event, which is basically just undoing the rewrite. Luckyly it will fire after the salesforce-handler and I can reliably cleanup the mess. But I would prefer something cleaner.